# How to ask Mathematica to extract all $y$-dependent terms in the given function $f(x,y,z)$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, parametric-functions, coefficients, multivalued

I have a very large three-variable function $f(x,y,z)$ for real variables $\{x,y,z\}$ (I had to put only part of my original function because of the limit of $30000$ characters).

> Is it possible to ask Mathematica to give/extract all the terms which are $y$-dependent? (the terms for $z$-dependent terms)

```
f[x_,y_,z_]:=-E^(I (5 x + y)) (-1 + x^2)^5 + 5 E^(I (7 x + y)) (-1 + x^2)^5 - 
 10 E^(I (9 x + y)) (-1 + x^2)^5 + 10 E^(I (11 x + y)) (-1 + x^2)^5 - 
 5 E^(I (13 x + y)) (-1 + x^2)^5 + E^(I (15 x + y)) (-1 + x^2)^5 + 
 5 E^(7 I x + 5 I z) (-1 + x^2)^5 - 
 10 E^(9 I x + 5 I z) (-1 + x^2)^5 + 
 10 E^(11 I x + 5 I z) (-1 + x^2)^5 - 
 5 E^(13 I x + 5 I z) (-1 + x^2)^5 - E^(5 I (x + z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 + 
 E^(5 I (3 x + z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 + (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (5 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 + (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (7 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 + (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (7 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 - (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (13 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 - (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (13 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 - (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (15 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 + (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (5 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 - (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (5 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 - (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (15 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 + (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (15 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 - 
 E^(I (5 x + 2 y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 + 
 5 E^(I (7 x + 2 y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 - 
 10 E^(I (9 x + 2 y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 + 
 10 E^(I (11 x + 2 y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 - 
 5 E^(I (13 x + 2 y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 + 
 E^(I (15 x + 2 y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 + (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (5 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 - (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (5 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 - (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (15 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 + (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (15 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 - (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (5 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 - (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (7 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 - (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (7 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 + (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (13 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 + (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (13 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 + (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (15 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 - 
 E^(I (5 x + y + 10 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 + 
 5 E^(I (7 x + y + 10 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 - 
 10 E^(I (9 x + y + 10 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 + 
 10 E^(I (11 x + y + 10 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 - 
 5 E^(I (13 x + y + 10 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 + 
 E^(I (15 x + y + 10 z)) (-1 + x^2)^5 - 
 2 E^(I (4 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 2 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (4 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 2 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (4 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 2 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (4 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 2 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (4 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 8 E^(I (6 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 8 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (6 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 8 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (6 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 8 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (6 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 8 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (6 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 10 E^(I (8 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 10 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (8 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 10 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (8 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 10 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (8 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 10 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (8 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 10 E^(I (12 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 10 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (12 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 10 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (12 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 10 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (12 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 10 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (12 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 8 E^(I (14 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 8 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (14 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 8 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (14 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 8 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (14 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 8 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (14 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 2 E^(I (16 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 2 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (16 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 2 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (16 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 2 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (16 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 2 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (16 x + y + z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 4 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (4 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 4 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (4 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 4 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (16 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 4 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (16 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 2 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (4 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 2 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (4 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 2 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (16 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 2 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (16 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 4 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (4 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 4 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (4 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 4 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (16 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 4 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (16 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 2 E^(I (4 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 2 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (4 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 2 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (4 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 2 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (4 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 2 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (4 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 8 E^(I (6 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 8 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (6 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 8 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (6 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 8 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (6 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 8 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (6 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 10 E^(I (8 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 10 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (8 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 10 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (8 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 10 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (8 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 10 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (8 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 10 E^(I (12 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 10 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (12 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 10 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (12 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 10 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (12 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 10 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (12 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 8 E^(I (14 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 8 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (14 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 8 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (14 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 8 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (14 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 8 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (14 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 2 E^(I (16 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 2 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (16 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 2 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (16 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 2 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (16 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) + 
 2 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (16 x + y + 9 z)) (-1 + x^2)^4 (1 + x^2) - 
 8 E^(I (3 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 8 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (3 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 8 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (3 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 8 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (3 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 8 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (3 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 24 E^(I (5 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 24 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (5 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 8 E^(I (7 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 8 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (7 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 40 E^(I (9 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 40 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (9 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 40 E^(I (11 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 40 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (11 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 8 E^(I (13 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 8 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (13 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 24 E^(I (15 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 24 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (15 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 8 E^(I (17 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 8 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (17 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 8 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (17 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 8 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (17 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 8 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (17 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 8 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (3 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 16 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (3 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 8 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (3 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 8 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (3 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 8 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (17 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 16 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (17 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 8 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (17 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 8 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (17 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 8 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (3 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 8 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (3 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 16 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (3 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 8 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (3 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 8 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (17 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 8 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (17 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 16 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (17 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 8 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (17 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 8 E^(I (3 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 8 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (3 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 8 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (3 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 8 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (3 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 8 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (3 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 24 E^(I (5 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 24 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (5 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 8 E^(I (7 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 8 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (7 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 40 E^(I (9 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 40 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (9 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 40 E^(I (11 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 40 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (11 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 8 E^(I (13 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 8 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (13 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 24 E^(I (15 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 24 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (15 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 8 E^(I (17 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 8 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (17 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 8 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (17 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 8 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (17 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 8 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (17 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 16 E^(I (2 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 + 
 16 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (2 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 - 
 16 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (2 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 + 
 16 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (2 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 - 
 16 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (2 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 - 
 8 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (6 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 + 
 24 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (6 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 - 
 8 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (6 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 + 
 8 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (14 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 - 
 24 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (14 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 + 
 8 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (14 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 + 
 16 E^(I (18 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 - 
 16 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (18 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 + 
 16 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (18 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 - 
 16 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (18 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 + 
 16 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (18 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 + 
 40 E^(I (2 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 + 
 40 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (2 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 - 
 40 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (2 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 + 
 40 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (2 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 - 
 40 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (2 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 - 
 80 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (4 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 + 
 80 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (4 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 + 
 80 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (16 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 - 
 80 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (16 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 - 
 40 E^(I (18 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 - 
 40 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (18 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 + 
 40 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (18 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 - 
 40 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (18 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 + 
 40 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (18 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 - 
 16 E^(I (2 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 + 
 16 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (2 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 - 
 16 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (2 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 + 
 16 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (2 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 - 
 16 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (2 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 + 
 8 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (6 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 - 
 24 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (6 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 + 
 8 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (6 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 - 
 8 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (14 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 + 
 24 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (14 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 - 
 8 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (14 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 + 
 16 E^(I (18 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 - 
 16 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (18 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 + 
 16 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (18 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 - 
 16 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (18 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 + 
 16 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (18 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2)^3 - 
 16 E^(I (x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + x^2)^4 + 
 16 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + x^2)^4 - 
 16 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + x^2)^4 + 
 16 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + x^2)^4 - 
 16 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + x^2)^4 + 
 16 E^(I (19 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + x^2)^4 - 
 16 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (19 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + x^2)^4 + 
 16 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (19 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + x^2)^4 - 
 16 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (19 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + x^2)^4 + 
 16 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (19 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + x^2)^4 - 
 16 E^(I (x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + x^2)^4 + 
 16 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + x^2)^4 - 
 16 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + x^2)^4 + 
 16 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + x^2)^4 - 
 16 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + x^2)^4 + 
 16 E^(I (19 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + x^2)^4 - 
 16 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (19 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + x^2)^4 + 
 16 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (19 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + x^2)^4 - 
 16 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (19 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + x^2)^4 + 
 16 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (19 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + x^2)^4 - 
 32 E^(I (y + 5 z)) (1 + x^2)^5 + 
 32 E^(I (20 x + y + 5 z)) (1 + x^2)^5 + 
 240 (-1)^(1/5) E^(I (10 x + y + 5 z))
   x (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 6 x^2 + x^4) - 
 8 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (10 x + y + 5 z))
   x (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 6 x^2 + x^4) - 
 8 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (10 x + y + 5 z))
   x (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 6 x^2 + x^4) + 
 240 (-1)^(4/5) E^(I (10 x + y + 5 z))
   x (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 6 x^2 + x^4) + 
 16 (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (4 x + y + 5 z)) (1 + x + x^2 + x^3)^2 (1 - x + 4 x^2 - x^3 + 
    x^4) + 16 (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (16 x + y + 5 z)) (1 + x + x^2 + x^3)^2 (1 - x + 4 x^2 - x^3 + 
    x^4) - 16 (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (4 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x - x^2 + x^3)^2 (1 + x + 4 x^2 + x^3 + 
    x^4) - 16 (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (16 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x - x^2 + x^3)^2 (1 + x + 4 x^2 + x^3 + 
    x^4) + 4 (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (6 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x)^2 (1 + x)^4 (2 - 3 x + 6 x^2 - 3 x^3 + 
    2 x^4) - 
 4 (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (14 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x)^2 (1 + x)^4 (2 - 3 x + 6 x^2 - 3 x^3 + 
    2 x^4) - 
 4 (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (6 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x)^2 (1 + x)^4 (2 - 3 x + 6 x^2 - 3 x^3 + 
    2 x^4) - 
 4 (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (14 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x)^2 (1 + x)^4 (2 - 3 x + 6 x^2 - 3 x^3 + 
    2 x^4) - 
 4 (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (6 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x)^2 (1 + x)^4 (2 - 3 x + 6 x^2 - 3 x^3 + 
    2 x^4) + 
 4 (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (14 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x)^2 (1 + x)^4 (2 - 3 x + 6 x^2 - 3 x^3 + 
    2 x^4) + 
 4 (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (6 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x)^4 (1 + x)^2 (2 + 3 x + 6 x^2 + 3 x^3 + 
    2 x^4) - 
 4 (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (14 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x)^4 (1 + x)^2 (2 + 3 x + 6 x^2 + 3 x^3 + 
    2 x^4) + 
 4 (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (6 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x)^4 (1 + x)^2 (2 + 3 x + 6 x^2 + 3 x^3 + 
    2 x^4) + 
 4 (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (14 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x)^4 (1 + x)^2 (2 + 3 x + 6 x^2 + 3 x^3 + 
    2 x^4) - 
 4 (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (6 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x)^4 (1 + x)^2 (2 + 3 x + 6 x^2 + 3 x^3 + 
    2 x^4) + 
 4 (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (14 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x)^4 (1 + x)^2 (2 + 3 x + 6 x^2 + 3 x^3 + 
    2 x^4) - 
 8 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (10 x + y + 5 z))
   x (-1 + x^2)^2 (3 + 2 x^2 + 3 x^4) - 
 8 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (10 x + y + 5 z))
   x (-1 + x^2)^2 (3 + 2 x^2 + 3 x^4) - (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (7 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 6 x^2 + 5 x^4) - 
 2 (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (9 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 6 x^2 + 5 x^4) - 
 2 (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (9 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 6 x^2 + 5 x^4) + 
 2 (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (11 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 6 x^2 + 5 x^4) + 
 2 (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (11 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 6 x^2 + 5 x^4) + (-1)^(1/5)
   E^(I (13 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 6 x^2 + 5 x^4) - (-1)^(
  3/5) E^(I (7 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 6 x^2 + 5 x^4) + (-1)^(
  4/5) E^(I (7 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 6 x^2 + 5 x^4) + (-1)^(
  3/5) E^(I (13 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 6 x^2 + 
    5 x^4) - (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (13 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 6 x^2 + 5 x^4) - (-1)^(1/5)
   E^(I (7 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 6 x^2 + 5 x^4) + (-1)^(2/5)
   E^(I (7 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 6 x^2 + 5 x^4) + (-1)^(1/5)
   E^(I (13 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 6 x^2 + 5 x^4) - (-1)^(
  2/5) E^(I (13 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 6 x^2 + 
    5 x^4) + (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (7 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 6 x^2 + 5 x^4) + 
 2 (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (9 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 6 x^2 + 5 x^4) + 
 2 (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (9 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 6 x^2 + 5 x^4) - 
 2 (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (11 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 6 x^2 + 5 x^4) - 
 2 (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (11 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 6 x^2 + 5 x^4) - (-1)^(4/5)
   E^(I (13 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 6 x^2 + 5 x^4) + 
 2 (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (9 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 14 x^2 + 5 x^4) - 
 2 (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (11 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 14 x^2 + 5 x^4) + 
 2 (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (9 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 14 x^2 + 5 x^4) - 
 2 (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (9 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 14 x^2 + 5 x^4) - 
 2 (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (11 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 14 x^2 + 5 x^4) + 
 2 (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (11 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 14 x^2 + 5 x^4) + 
 2 (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (9 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 14 x^2 + 5 x^4) - 
 2 (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (9 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 14 x^2 + 5 x^4) - 
 2 (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (11 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 14 x^2 + 5 x^4) + 
 2 (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (11 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 14 x^2 + 5 x^4) - 
 2 (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (9 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 14 x^2 + 5 x^4) + 
 2 (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (11 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 14 x^2 + 5 x^4) + 
 2 (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (9 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 - 8 x + 14 x^2 - 8 x^3 + 
    5 x^4) - 
 2 (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (11 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 - 8 x + 14 x^2 - 8 x^3 + 
    5 x^4) - 
 2 (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (9 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 - 8 x + 14 x^2 - 8 x^3 + 
    5 x^4) + 
 2 (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (11 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 - 8 x + 14 x^2 - 8 x^3 + 
    5 x^4) - 
 2 (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (8 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x)^2 (1 + x)^4 (5 - 2 x + 10 x^2 - 2 x^3 + 
    5 x^4) + 
 2 (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (12 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x)^2 (1 + x)^4 (5 - 2 x + 10 x^2 - 
    2 x^3 + 5 x^4) + 
 2 (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (8 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x)^2 (1 + x)^4 (5 - 2 x + 10 x^2 - 2 x^3 + 
    5 x^4) + 
 2 (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (12 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x)^2 (1 + x)^4 (5 - 2 x + 10 x^2 - 
    2 x^3 + 5 x^4) + 
 2 (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (8 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x)^2 (1 + x)^4 (5 - 2 x + 10 x^2 - 2 x^3 + 
    5 x^4) - 
 2 (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (12 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x)^2 (1 + x)^4 (5 - 2 x + 10 x^2 - 
    2 x^3 + 5 x^4) - 
 2 (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (8 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x)^4 (1 + x)^2 (5 + 2 x + 10 x^2 + 2 x^3 + 
    5 x^4) + 
 2 (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (12 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x)^4 (1 + x)^2 (5 + 2 x + 10 x^2 + 
    2 x^3 + 5 x^4) - 
 2 (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (8 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x)^4 (1 + x)^2 (5 + 2 x + 10 x^2 + 2 x^3 + 
    5 x^4) - 
 2 (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (12 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x)^4 (1 + x)^2 (5 + 2 x + 10 x^2 + 
    2 x^3 + 5 x^4) + 
 2 (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (8 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x)^4 (1 + x)^2 (5 + 2 x + 10 x^2 + 2 x^3 + 
    5 x^4) - 
 2 (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (12 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x)^4 (1 + x)^2 (5 + 2 x + 10 x^2 + 
    2 x^3 + 5 x^4) + 
 2 (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (9 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 8 x + 14 x^2 + 8 x^3 + 
    5 x^4) - 
 2 (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (11 x + y + 4 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 8 x + 14 x^2 + 8 x^3 + 
    5 x^4) - 
 2 (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (9 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 8 x + 14 x^2 + 8 x^3 + 
    5 x^4) + 
 2 (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (11 x + y + 6 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (5 + 8 x + 14 x^2 + 8 x^3 + 
    5 x^4) + 
 16 (-1)^(2/5) E^(I (10 x + y + 5 z))
   x (-1 + x^2)^2 (7 - 6 x^2 + 7 x^4) + 
 16 (-1)^(3/5) E^(I (10 x + y + 5 z))
   x (-1 + x^2)^2 (7 - 6 x^2 + 7 x^4) - (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (7 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (9 + 14 x^2 + 9 x^4) - (-1)^(4/5)
   E^(I (7 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (9 + 14 x^2 + 9 x^4) + (-1)^(
  2/5) E^(I (13 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (9 + 14 x^2 + 
    9 x^4) + (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (13 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (9 + 14 x^2 + 9 x^4) + (-1)^(1/5)
   E^(I (7 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (9 + 14 x^2 + 9 x^4) + (-1)^(
  3/5) E^(I (7 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (9 + 14 x^2 + 
    9 x^4) - (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (13 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (9 + 14 x^2 + 9 x^4) - (-1)^(3/5)
   E^(I (13 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (9 + 14 x^2 + 9 x^4) + (-1)^(
  2/5) E^(I (5 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (11 + 26 x^2 + 
    11 x^4) + (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (5 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (11 + 26 x^2 + 11 x^4) - (-1)^(2/5)
   E^(I (15 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (11 + 26 x^2 + 11 x^4) - (-1)^(
  4/5) E^(I (15 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (11 + 26 x^2 + 
    11 x^4) - (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (5 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (11 + 26 x^2 + 11 x^4) - (-1)^(3/5)
   E^(I (5 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (11 + 26 x^2 + 11 x^4) + (-1)^(
  1/5) E^(I (15 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (11 + 26 x^2 + 
    11 x^4) + (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (15 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (11 + 26 x^2 + 11 x^4) + (-1)^(2/5)
   E^(I (5 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (13 + 22 x^2 + 13 x^4) + (-1)^(
  4/5) E^(I (5 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (13 + 22 x^2 + 
    13 x^4) + (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (7 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (13 + 22 x^2 + 13 x^4) - (-1)^(1/5)
   E^(I (13 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (13 + 22 x^2 + 13 x^4) - (-1)^(
  2/5) E^(
  I (15 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (13 + 22 x^2 + 13 x^4) - (-1)^(4/5)
   E^(I (15 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (13 + 22 x^2 + 13 x^4) - (-1)^(
  1/5) E^(I (5 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (13 + 22 x^2 + 
    13 x^4) - (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (5 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (13 + 22 x^2 + 13 x^4) - (-1)^(4/5)
   E^(I (7 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (13 + 22 x^2 + 13 x^4) + (-1)^(
  4/5) E^(I (13 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (13 + 22 x^2 + 
    13 x^4) + (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (15 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (13 + 22 x^2 + 13 x^4) + (-1)^(3/5)
   E^(I (15 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (13 + 22 x^2 + 13 x^4) + 
 2 (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (9 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (15 + 26 x^2 + 15 x^4) - 
 2 (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (11 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (15 + 26 x^2 + 15 x^4) - 
 2 (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (9 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (15 + 26 x^2 + 15 x^4) + 
 2 (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (11 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (15 + 26 x^2 + 15 x^4) - 
 2 (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (9 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (15 + 34 x^2 + 15 x^4) - 
 2 (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (9 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (15 + 34 x^2 + 15 x^4) + 
 2 (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (11 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (15 + 34 x^2 + 15 x^4) + 
 2 (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (11 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (15 + 34 x^2 + 15 x^4) + 
 2 (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (9 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (15 + 34 x^2 + 15 x^4) + 
 2 (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (9 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (15 + 34 x^2 + 15 x^4) - 
 2 (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (11 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (15 + 34 x^2 + 15 x^4) - 
 2 (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (11 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (15 + 34 x^2 + 15 x^4) - (-1)^(1/5)
   E^(I (5 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (25 + 46 x^2 + 25 x^4) + (-1)^(
  1/5) E^(I (15 x + y + 2 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (25 + 46 x^2 + 
    25 x^4) + (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (5 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (25 + 46 x^2 + 25 x^4) - (-1)^(4/5)
   E^(I (15 x + y + 8 z)) (-1 + x^2)^3 (25 + 46 x^2 + 25 x^4) + 
 40 E^(I (6 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 7 x^2 + 7 x^4 + x^6) - 
 40 E^(I (14 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 7 x^2 + 7 x^4 + x^6) + 
 4 E^(I (3 x + y + 4 z)) (1 + x^2)^2 (-1 - 13 x^2 + 13 x^4 + x^6) - 
 4 E^(I (17 x + y + 4 z)) (1 + x^2)^2 (-1 - 13 x^2 + 13 x^4 + x^6) + 
 4 E^(I (3 x + y + 6 z)) (1 + x^2)^2 (-1 - 13 x^2 + 13 x^4 + x^6) - 
 4 E^(I (17 x + y + 6 z)) (1 + x^2)^2 (-1 - 13 x^2 + 13 x^4 + x^6) + 
 8 (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (6 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (2 - 19 x - 22 x^2 - 50 x^3 - 
    22 x^4 - 19 x^5 + 2 x^6) + 
 8 (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (14 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (2 - 19 x - 22 x^2 - 50 x^3 - 
    22 x^4 - 19 x^5 + 2 x^6) - 
 40 (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (6 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (2 - x + 10 x^2 - 6 x^3 + 10 x^4 - 
    x^5 + 2 x^6) - 
 40 (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (14 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (2 - x + 10 x^2 - 6 x^3 + 10 x^4 - 
    x^5 + 2 x^6) + 
 40 (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (6 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (2 + x + 10 x^2 + 6 x^3 + 10 x^4 + 
    x^5 + 2 x^6) + 
 40 (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (14 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (2 + x + 10 x^2 + 6 x^3 + 10 x^4 + 
    x^5 + 2 x^6) - 
 8 (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (6 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (2 + 19 x - 22 x^2 + 50 x^3 - 
    22 x^4 + 19 x^5 + 2 x^6) - 
 8 (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (14 x + y + 5 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (2 + 19 x - 22 x^2 + 50 x^3 - 
    22 x^4 + 19 x^5 + 2 x^6) - 
 4 (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (3 x + y + 4 z)) (1 + x^2)^2 (-3 - 7 x^2 + 7 x^4 + 3 x^6) - 
 4 (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (3 x + y + 4 z)) (1 + x^2)^2 (-3 - 7 x^2 + 7 x^4 + 3 x^6) + 
 4 (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (3 x + y + 4 z)) (1 + x^2)^2 (-3 - 7 x^2 + 7 x^4 + 3 x^6) + 
 4 (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (17 x + y + 4 z)) (1 + x^2)^2 (-3 - 7 x^2 + 7 x^4 + 3 x^6) + 
 4 (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (17 x + y + 4 z)) (1 + x^2)^2 (-3 - 7 x^2 + 7 x^4 + 3 x^6) - 
 4 (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (17 x + y + 4 z)) (1 + x^2)^2 (-3 - 7 x^2 + 7 x^4 + 3 x^6) - 
 4 (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (3 x + y + 6 z)) (1 + x^2)^2 (-3 - 7 x^2 + 7 x^4 + 3 x^6) + 
 4 (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (3 x + y + 6 z)) (1 + x^2)^2 (-3 - 7 x^2 + 7 x^4 + 3 x^6) + 
 4 (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (3 x + y + 6 z)) (1 + x^2)^2 (-3 - 7 x^2 + 7 x^4 + 3 x^6) + 
 4 (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (17 x + y + 6 z)) (1 + x^2)^2 (-3 - 7 x^2 + 7 x^4 + 3 x^6) - 
 4 (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (17 x + y + 6 z)) (1 + x^2)^2 (-3 - 7 x^2 + 7 x^4 + 3 x^6) - 
 4 (-1)^(4/5) E^(
  I (17 x + y + 6 z)) (1 + x^2)^2 (-3 - 7 x^2 + 7 x^4 + 3 x^6) - 
 4 (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (4 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (3 + 13 x^2 + 13 x^4 + 3 x^6) - 
 4 (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (4 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (3 + 13 x^2 + 13 x^4 + 3 x^6) + 
 4 (-1)^(1/5) E^(
  I (16 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (3 + 13 x^2 + 13 x^4 + 3 x^6) + 
 4 (-1)^(3/5) E^(
  I (16 x + y + 3 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (3 + 13 x^2 + 13 x^4 + 3 x^6) + 
 4 (-1)^(2/5) E^(
  I (4 x + y + 7 z)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (3 + 13 x^2 + 13 x^4 + 3 x^6)
```

Comment: I would try something like, `DeleteCases[List@@f[x,y,z],FreeQ[#,y]&]`

Comment: Try:  Select[f[x, y, z], ! FreeQ[#, y] &]

Comment: This is hardly a `minimal working example`. You should use examples that are short enough that you can also provide the expected output for the given input.

Comment: @BobHanlon Yes; but I need to do it for this particular example.